# C++ class initializing list and passing functions

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, initialization

I really searched the web for this but never came up with an answer. I know two ways of initializing a class and one of them doesn't work when I try to pass a function. Can you help me understand why this happens? And what method should I use? Thanks in advance!

```
void func(int i){
    cout << "GG " << i; 
}

class ac{
public:
    int a;
    function<void()> sh = bind(&func, a);

    /*ac (int i){   This does not work
        a = i;
    }*/

    ac (int i) : a(i) {};   // but this does

    void go (){
        sh();
    }
};

int main() {
    ac ac1(5);
    ac1.go();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Thanks for all the responses, this was a lot quicker than I thought. It seems like the output of the first example was some random garbage, I wasn't sure that's why I hesitated to detail the output.

Comment: You could massively improve this question by replacing "does not work" with an actual problem description.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As @ChristianHackl said, "does not work" doesn't help readers of your question figure out what behavior you're seeing that you don't think is right. Describe what you think should  happen and what actually happens. In order for readers to understand the problem, you also should post code that is complete enough to actually compile and run and show the problem. Don't make people guess at what `#include` directives the code has.

Comment: I'm sorry, I said "doesnt work" on purpose because I wasn't sure if the output was some random value or address of something. But got your point :D

Comment: If you don't plan on *changing* the `std::function` member, then I suggest you replace it with a member function. Easy peasy. :)

Comment: Actually my intention is to pass a function with any number of arguments into the class. I thought I could use bind for that but I got an error even with hardcoded version above. Also I still haven't got it the work without a hard coded function. How can I pass the name of the function I want to bind into the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
ac (int i){
    a = i;
}
```

Does not work since `sh` is initialized using an uninitialized value of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Binding happens when you call bind.

And `bind` happens in constructor initialization list.

So in your code, when your bind the function, you bind it with **current** value of `a` - which is random unless it was inititalized in constructor initialization list.

Answer (score 0):

When you do in class initialization it is just a short hand to have that done by the constructor if you do not do it yourself.  That means

```
ac (int i){
    a = i;
}
```

Becomes

```
ac (int i) : a(garbage), sh(bind(&func, a)){
    a = i;
}
```

So now we have a default initialized (which in this case means it contains garbage) `a` being used for the function so we have garbage.  The reason `a` comes before `sh` is that is the way the declred in the class and that dictates the order of initialization.

The second example works as the constructor is treated as

```
ac (int i) : a(i), sh(bind(&func, a)){
    a = i;
}
```

And now when we bind `a` to `func` `a` is initialized to an actual value.

Comment: The second example is wrong. `a()` results in zero-initialisation, so `a` is guaranteed to be 0.

Comment: Mentioning this in case OP overlooked it - the binding permanently uses the value of `a` at the time (i.e. `i`); it will not re-check the class member `a` each time the function is called