# C++ Passing function with not defined number of arguments to the class

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, reference

I was tackling with this problem and I asked [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732796/c-class-initializing-list-and-passing-functions) here, but even after I get the result I couldn't get the thing work. And before we start, I used pointers to pass functions before in C but I'm relatively new to C++ and pointers don't pass functions with unknown arguments.

My question is:

How do I get to pass a function to a class without necessarily knowing how many arguments does it take. What should I do if I want to feed the function that I want to bind into the class? Something like:

```
ac ac1(args_of_the_object, a_function_with_its_arguments)
```

I got the bind function work in the class initializing list, thanks to anyone who helped,

```
function<void()> sh = bind(&hard_coded_function_name, argument);
```

and I can set the argument when creating an object of the class:

```
class_name(type ar) : argument(ar) {};
```

You got the point. Thing is, I can not pass the function itself to the class. I tried using this with a slight modification in class initializing list:

```
class_name cl1(args, bind(&func_i_want, arguments));
```

But it resulted in stack dump error.

Thanks!

Edit: (It was too long for a comment)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void diffuse(float k){
    cout << " WP! " << k;  
}

class Sphere{
    public:
        function<void()> sh;
        Sphere (function<void()> X) : sh(X) {};

        //another try
        function<void()> sh;
        Sphere (void (*f)(float)) : sh(bind(&f, arg)) {}; // This is not what I want obviously still I tried it and it doesn't work either.

        void Shader(){
            sh();
        }
};


Color trace(vector<Sphere>& objs){

    // find a specific instance of the class which is obj in this case
    // Basically what I'm trying to do is
    // assigning a specific function to each object of the class and calling them with the Shader()

    obj.Shader();

    // Run  the function I assigned to that object, note that it will eventually return a value, but right now I can't even get this to work.
}

int main() {
    vector<Sphere> objects;
    Sphere sp1(bind(&diffuse, 5));
    Sphere sp1(&diffusea); // I used this for second example
    objects.push_back(sp1);

    trace(objects);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the whole code if you want to see: [LINK](https://codeshare.io/AfPcD)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need specific code that you tried that failed.

Comment: I edited the post, and fyi I'm trying to assign a different characteristic function to every object of the class. I'm going to use it to create programmable shaders for my ray-tracer which works fine now. Obviously I couldn't post the whole thing, it was too long for that. But I hope the code I posted will help you. Thanks.

Comment: "Obviously I couldn't post the whole thing" <-- this is the problem. Reduce the example down to a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), *then* we can help you fix it. I can't tell what your problem is here - you gave us a `Sphere` class, with constructors that take one argument, but you're trying to construct them with three arguments. I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, actually I'm pretty sure that's all there's to it. I forgot to delete the other arguments from the sp1 but that's not the problem anyway. The program works fine. I WOULD post the whole code if I had this done and having trouble with returning a certain data type. I will make use of this on a larger project but I have problems on this little section. Basically my goal is to assign a different function to each object at the construction and call them with same name later. like obj1.Shader() would run func1() and obj2.Shader() would run func2()

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only store data whose type is known (at compile time).

However, you can pass the function as an argument.  Function templates take care of various types.

```
class Sphere {
    public:
        template<typename F>
        void shade(F&& f);
};
```

For example

```
void functionA(int) {}
void functionB(double) {}

Sphere sphere;

sphere.shade(functionA);
sphere.shade(functionB);
```

Comment: Thank you but can you explain it a little bit in detail? Also I heard that templates are not good for performance. Thanks.